# How to convert yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' to MM-dd-yyyy in swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, dateformatter

Hello I need to change the date format

I getting a response from backend like

**dob = "1989-03-06T00:00:00Z";**

in my case, I write the following code but my app is crashed i think my current date format is wrong.

```swift
func DateFromWebtoApp(_ date: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    return  dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
}
```

Comment: try changing the format to ````dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"````

Comment: No, I already try in this way also

Comment: @ghrixghrix - Am I correct in assuming that this resulting `MM-dd-yyyy` string is for presentation in your UI?

Answer (score 2):

Please look at the date string. There are no milliseconds (`S`) and the `Z` is a format specifier (no single quotes).

Further for an arbitrary date format add always a fixed `Locale`

```
func dateFromWebtoApp(_ dateString: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Its work on my side.

```
func DateFromWebtoApp(_ date: String) -> String
{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
    return  dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
}
```

Comment: Have you try with dateFormatter time zome as a current time ?

Answer (score 0):

Since that input date string is in a ISO complaint date format you can use `ISO8601DateFormatter`.

```
func dateFromWebtoApp(_ inDate: String) -> String? {
    let inFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    if let date = inFormatter.date(from: inDate) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Since constructing date formatters is somewhat expensive it might be worthwhile to declare them outside of the function and keep them around if possible

Answer (score 0):

Date formatters are notoriously computationally intensive to create. They’re also computationally expensive to change the `dateFormat`. So I’d suggest you declare two date formatter properties up front, and instantiate them once and only once.

```
let isoDateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()

let dobFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    return formatter
}()
```

The first, `isoDateFormatter` is for converting strings from your backend into `Date` objects. By using `ISO8601DateFormatter`, it gets you out of the business of manually configuring the `locale` for a `DateFormatter`.

The second, `dobFormatter` is for converting the date of birth `Date` object into a string to be presented in your UI. For this second formatter, please note that:

- I don’t use `dateFormat`, but rather `dateStyle` (so the result honors the particular device’s date localization preferences, where UK users will see “6 Mar 1989”, but US users will see “Mar 6, 2019”). Use `.short` rather than `.medium` if you *really* want to see `dd/MM/yy` for UK users and `MM/dd/yy` for US users. But I personally like the medium format, as it is both reasonably concise but also completely unambiguous. Of, if I have space, I use the long format, which represents date most naturally (e.g. “March 6, 2019” rather than “Mar 6, 2019”). Do whatever your UI demands.

  But if this is for presentation to the end user, you really should avoid hard-coded date format strings as users want to see dates presented in a manner consistent with their personal device-wide localization settings, not what one app or the other prefers. And there’s no reason to limit your app to US users, because some day you might want to reach a broader audience.
- I set the time zone for this output formatter to be GMT because this string represents a date, not a combined date/time. E.g., `1989-03-06T00:00:00Z`, which is midnight on March 6, 1989 GMT, translates to is 4pm on March 5th for us in California. But when you present the birthdate, you want to say March 6th, not March 5th. In short, you want to ignore the time and timezone information. You do this by using GMT/UTC/Zulu for your output date formatter.

Anyway, you’d then use it like so:

```
let input = "1989-03-06T00:00:00Z"
if let dob = isoDateFormatter.date(from: input) {
    let output = dobFormatter.string(from: dob)
}
```